# What kind of connection is this?

Tags: connector, hacking

I am trying to control my ventilator with a relay. I have found schematics of how to install it. Basically, I would like to immitate a wall switch with a relay to start the ventilator. The board of the ventilator has a weird connector I have never seen before. Does anyone know, what kind of connector is this? I would like to have a "clean" connection with my relay.

[image: Connector top view]
[image: Connector front view]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It looks like a PCB edge connector, where another PCB slots into that connector.  There would be copper "fingers" on the PCB to line up with the terminals, and a slot to mate with the key on the connector pictured.

Comment: I'm with Simon in thinking it's probably an edge connector. If this is a one-off project and you don't have the other end that plugs into it, I'd be looking to replace it for a more standard Molex connector or directly soldered wire leads.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It makes sense now. As far as I understand the board should enter the space in the middle. Luckily I have some grid boards with edges suitable for such contacts (8x)! I will try it to see if it fits. I guess I will also have to cut one in the middle to fit in there.